# Pandas: Force position of column in DataFrame (without knowing all columns)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame and don't know the names of all columns. However, I know there's a column called `"N_DOC"` and I want this to be the first column of the DataFrame - (while keeping all other columns, regardless its order).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reorder the columns of a datframe with `reindex`:

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols.remove('N_DOC')
df.reindex(['N_DOC'] + cols, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'N_DOC':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

c = 'N_DOC'
df.insert(0, c, df.pop(c))
```

Or:

```
df.insert(0, 'N_DOC', df.pop('N_DOC'))
```

---

```
print (df)
   N_DOC  A  B  C  E  F
0      1  a  4  7  5  a
1      3  b  5  8  3  a
2      5  c  4  9  6  a
3      7  d  5  4  9  b
4      1  e  5  2  2  b
5      0  f  4  3  4  b
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple, one line, solution using DataFrame masking:

```
import pandas as pd

# Building sample dataset.
cols = ['N_DOCa', 'N_DOCb', 'N_DOCc', 'N_DOCd', 'N_DOCe', 'N_DOC']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

# Re-order columns.
df = df[['N_DOC'] + df.columns.drop('N_DOC').tolist()]
```

#### Before:

```
Index(['N_DOCa', 'N_DOCb', 'N_DOCc', 'N_DOCd', 'N_DOCe', 'N_DOC'], dtype='object')
```

#### After:

```
Index(['N_DOC', 'N_DOCa', 'N_DOCb', 'N_DOCc', 'N_DOCd', 'N_DOCe'], dtype='object')
```